# SOQL query for more than one field to exclude null values

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I have around 12 fields. Trying to write a SOQL query for more than one field to exclude null values.

For single field which is not null, I am able to get the records. I want to a SOQL to get the records for all 12 fields which are not null.

Below is the SOQL to get the records for single field which is not null:

SELECT Name ,AccountNumber, OwnerId,ParentId, Data_Center_BDE__c,Tele_CDE__c,DMS_Owner__c,Primary_Local_Market_Rep_1__c,Information_Governance_Rep__c,DM_Cloud_Sales_Rep__c,Primary_BDE__c,Primary_CDE__c,Primary_BDE_DB_R__c,Primary_CDE_DB_R__c,Library_Services_BDE__c FROM Account WHERE Data_Center_BDE__c != NULL

similarly I want to write for other 12 fields which are not null. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query is working for my question.

SELECT Name ,AccountNumber, OwnerId,ParentId, Data_Center_BDE__c,Tele_CDE__c,DMS_Owner__c,Primary_Local_Market_Rep_1__c,Information_Governance_Rep__c,DM_Cloud_Sales_Rep__c,Primary_BDE__c,Primary_CDE__c,Primary_BDE_DB_R__c,Primary_CDE_DB_R__c,Library_Services_BDE__c
FROM Account where Data_Center_BDE__c != NULL and Tele_CDE__c != NULL and DMS_Owner__c != NULL and Primary_Local_Market_Rep_1__c != NULL and
Information_Governance_Rep__c != NULL and DM_Cloud_Sales_Rep__c != NULL and Primary_BDE__c != NULL and Primary_CDE__c != NULL and Primary_BDE_DB_R__c != NULL and Primary_CDE_DB_R__c != NULL and Library_Services_BDE__c != NULL

Comment: Glad you managed to get your answer. Would appreciate it if you marked mine as accepted if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use `AND`

```
SELECT Name ,AccountNumber, OwnerId,ParentId, Data_Center_BDE__c,Tele_CDE__c,DMS_Owner__c,Primary_Local_Market_Rep_1__c,Information_Governance_Rep__c,DM_Cloud_Sales_Rep__c,Primary_BDE__c,Primary_CDE__c,Primary_BDE_DB_R__c,Primary_CDE_DB_R__c,Library_Services_BDE__c FROM Account WHERE Data_Center_BDE__c != NULL AND OtherField != NULL
```

The above would be for 2 fields. Add as many more as you need.